# How can I cast Rc<RefCell<Box<MyTrait> to Rc<RefCell<Box<MyStruct>>>

Tags: casting, rust, dynamic-dispatch, trait-objects

I have a trait `MyTrait` and a struct `MyStruct` that implements `MyTrait`.

I also have a function that accepts `Rc<RefCell<Box<MyTrait>>>` as an argument.

Somewhere in the code I create an instance of `Rc<RefCell<Box<MyStruct>>>`:

```
let my_struct = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Box::new(MyStruct)));
```

When I pass `my_struct` to my function I get a compiler error:

error: mismatched types:
 expected `alloc::rc::Rc<core::cell::RefCell<Box<MyTrait>>>`,
    found `alloc::rc::Rc<core::cell::RefCell<Box<MyStruct>>>`

I try to fix that by creating an instance of `Rc<RefCell<Box<MyStruct>>>` by explicitly specifying the type I need:

```
let my_struct: Rc<RefCell<Box<MyTrait>>> = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Box::new(MyStruct)));
```

In this case passing `my_struct` to my function works fine, however I can't access any `MyStruct` specific fields via `my_struct` variable anymore. And it doesn't seem to be a way to cast down `Rc<RefCell<Box<MyTrait>>>` to `Rc<RefCell<Box<MyStruct>>>`.

How can I go around this problem?

Comment: A `Box<Trait>` is known as a *trait object* (your extra layers of `Rc` and `RefCell` are extraneous and you should have removed them as part of creating an [MCVE](/help/mcve)). You also were **super** close with the right keywords, but it's more commonly referred to as *downcasting* as opposed to *casting down*.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please note, that my question was explicitly about Rc<RefCell<Box<Trait>>> as I need referenced-counted pointer with mutability. If I used just Rc<Trait> or Box<Trait> I wouldn't have any problem. I would just create an instance of `Rc<MyStruct>`: `let my_struct: Rc<MyStruct> = Rc::new(MyStruct)` and then pass it to the function that accepts `Rc<MyTrait>` and that would worked just fine. The problem happens when I add this extra RefCell bit and that's what I wanted to highlight in my question.