# Create two copies of Rc<RefCell<Box<dyn SomeTrait>>>, but one is the concrete instance

Tags: unit-testing, rust, mocking

I'm trying to mock out the serial port object provided by `serialport::new()` and having an awful time with it. The `Rc<RefCell<dyn SomeTrait>>` pattern is one I've been using for a while now for any singleton dependencies - like a serial port - and I've grown accustomed to it. It works and it lets me use `mockall` to write highly focused unit tests where all dependencies are mocked out.

But, today I ran into `serialport::new()`, which returns a `Box<dyn SerialPort>`, and I can't figure out a way to convert that into `Rc<RefCell<dyn SerialPort>>`. So I wrapped the whole box and ended up with `Rc<RefCell<Box<dyn SerialPort>>>`. But now I can't get my unit test to compile without defining the mock object in `TestContext` as another `Rc<RefCell<Box<dyn SerialPort>>>` - which would prevent me from being able to actually invoke special mock-related methods, like `.expect_send()`.

I could use some help here. What follows is my use-case recreated in the simplest form possible as well as the compiler error that I get when building the test.

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

/// This is not my code. This is a simplified version of the serialport crate.
mod serialport {
    pub trait SerialPort {
        fn send(&self);
    }

    pub struct SomeConcreteSerialPort {}

    impl SerialPort for SomeConcreteSerialPort {
        fn send(&self) {}
    }

    pub fn new() -> Box<dyn SerialPort> {
        Box::new(SomeConcreteSerialPort {})
    }
}

struct MyStruct {
    port: Rc<RefCell<Box<dyn serialport::SerialPort>>>,
}

impl MyStruct {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            port: Rc::new(RefCell::new(serialport::new())),
        }
    }

    fn do_send(&self) {
        self.port.borrow().send();
    }
}

fn main() {
    let my_struct = MyStruct::new();
    my_struct.do_send();
    println!("The foo is done!");
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    use mockall::mock;
    use std::cell::RefCell;
    use std::rc::Rc;

    use crate::serialport;
    use crate::MyStruct;

    mock! {
        SerialPort {}

        impl serialport::SerialPort for SerialPort {
            fn send(&self);
        }
    }

    struct TestContext {
        mock_port: Rc<RefCell<Box<MockSerialPort>>>,
        testable: MyStruct,
    }

    impl TestContext {
        fn new() -> Self {
            let mock_port = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Box::new(MockSerialPort::new())));
            Self {
                mock_port: Rc::clone(&mock_port),
                testable: MyStruct { port: mock_port },
            }
        }
    }


    #[test]
    fn test_happy_path() {
        let context = TestContext::new();

        context.mock_port.borrow().expect_send().once();

        context.testable.do_send();
    }
}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:71:44
   |
71 |                 testable: MyStruct { port: mock_port },
   |                                            ^^^^^^^^^ expected trait object `dyn SerialPort`, found struct `MockSerialPort`
   |
   = note: expected struct `Rc<RefCell<Box<(dyn SerialPort + 'static)>>>`
              found struct `Rc<RefCell<Box<MockSerialPort>>>`
```

I've also published the code to a GitHub repo if you'd like to reproduce it locally: https://github.com/DavidZemon/MockingProblems/

Comment: Is there a reason you need the box? Can `serialport::new()` return `Rc<RefCell<dyn SerialPort>>` instead? Then you don't need to internal `Box` and can just cast `Rc<RefCell<MockSerialPort>>` to `Rc<RefCell<dyn serialport::SerialPort>>`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30861295/how-do-i-pass-rcrefcellboxmystruct-to-a-function-accepting-rcrefcellbox

Comment: Why you need a `RefCell` if `send()` takes shared `&self`?

Comment: @PitaJ, I can not drop the box - it's not my code. I included the code in my sample for simplicity's sake, but it is from the serialport crate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Frxstrem explained well why this is impossible, I want to suggest a solution.

Instead of using `Rc` from the *outside*, you can use `Rc` from the *inside*. That is, just use `Box<dyn SerialPort>`, but for the tests, use a type that wraps `Rc<MockSerialPort>` (or `Rc<RefCell<MockSerialPort>>`) and implements `SerialPort` by forwarding to the inner `MockSerialPort`:

```rust
struct MyStruct {
    port: Box<dyn serialport::SerialPort>,
}

impl MyStruct {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            port: serialport::new(),
        }
    }

    fn do_send(&self) {
        self.port.send();
    }
}

mock! {
    SerialPort {}

    impl serialport::SerialPort for SerialPort {
        fn send(&self);
    }
}

struct SharedMockSerialPort(Rc<MockSerialPort>);
impl serialport::SerialPort for SharedMockSerialPort {
    fn send(&self) {
        self.0.send();
    }
}

struct TestContext {
    mock_port: Rc<MockSerialPort>,
    testable: MyStruct,
}

impl TestContext {
    fn new() -> Self {
        let mock_port = Rc::new(MockSerialPort::new());
        Self {
            mock_port: Rc::clone(&mock_port),
            testable: MyStruct {
                port: Box::new(SharedMockSerialPort(mock_port)),
            },
        }
    }
}
```

This is a better design even for other cases, because it avoids the overhead of `Rc` and `RefCell` for non-test code.

Comment: Tedious as this solution is, it at least _works_. Thank you. I was able to get my simple example repo working, even after adding some additional detail (the real `serialport::SerialPort` also inherits from Send) and therefore needing to swap `Rc` out for `Arc` and tossing a `Mutex` into the mix.

I was also able to take this example and get it compiling in my real app. It doesn't pass my first unit test yet, but "compiling" is good enough for tonight and I'll poke at it more in the morning. For now, your answer certainly solves the question I asked at the top. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We can ignore `RefCell` completely, and consider the question of turning `Rc<Box<T>>` into `Rc<Box<dyn Trait>>` when `T` implements `Trait`.

To be possible, this must not change the memory representation of the value inside of the `Rc`, so `Box<T>` and `Box<dyn Trait>` must have the same memory representation. However, `Box<T>` is a thin pointer, which means that it only contains an address to the value on the heap, whereas `Box<dyn Trait>` is a fat pointer, which contains both the address to the value and the address to the vtable of `T` that contains the type information (such as methods) at runtime.

So `Box<dyn Trait>` is larger than `Box<T>` and thus has a different memory layout, and it follows that it's impossible to turn a `Rc<Box<T>>` into a `Rc<Box<dyn Trait>>` (or in any way produce two `Rc`s with these types that point to the same value). The extra layer of indirection caused by `Box` (or any other pointer type) is what makes this impossible.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of why I was trying the impossible.